# Chrome extension disabling events in angular application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, events

I am building a chrome extension that overlays a responsive grid on top of my angular application. The problem is my events are disabled when I enable the extension and have to refresh the page in order to get back the events. Has anyone ran into a problem such as this before?

Comment: does your events listeners like Angular directives get disabled or other listeners in host tab?

Comment: Just Angular directives.

Comment: So after some investigation I found that events do fire because I used a regular onclick on a button in my angular application and it work. I think the issue is ng-click. For some reason the overlay from the chrome extension is messing with how ng-click works. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without having your exact HTML structure, but as a guess:

- after you edit a node, you need to [compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) it for scope, in order to have directives working. and since you're doing it on hosted page and you don't have access to it's scope, be careful with that.
- you may loose your directives if your extension appends [another version of Angular](http://www.mattburkedev.com/multiple-angular-versions-on-the-same-page/) to hosted page *(also other conflicts and resolves for this issue)*.

Comment: My angular application works fine, if I don't use the chrome extension. All the chrome extension is doing is putting a grid overlay onto the page to test the responsiveness. For example, when I enable the extension my click events in angular stop working. The chrome extension use generic HTML and JS. No jquery or anything just what the google chrome API gives you.

Comment: @user2009639 you said "overlay". HTML element can cover each other and prevent mouse events to receive to underlaying layers. Have you disabled click events of the "overlay" by something like css 'pointer-events:none;' ? I mean I think you need to disable click events for overlay.

Comment: I have done that and it still doesn't work. I can click the element under the overlay, but the event isn't firing.  If I go on another website and use the grid extension the click events work fine, but for some reason with my angular application the click events don't fire when I use it.